# Finding the dimension of the intersection of two vector spaces given their basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I'm given the basis of two $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces $U$ and $V$:
\begin{gather} 
B_V = \{(-1,0,1,-1), (0,-1,0,0), (-1,-1,1,3)\} \\[2pt]
B_U = \{(1,0,1,1), (0,1,2,0)\} 
\end{gather}
So $\dim(V) = 3$ and $\dim(U) = 2$. I need to determine the dimension of $U \cap V$, **without** explicitly calculating its elements.

I know that $\dim(U \cap V )$ must be either $1$ or $2$, and it cannot be $0$ because, if it was,
$$
\dim(U+V) = \dim(U) + \dim(V) - \dim(U \cap V) = 3 + 2 - 0 = 5, 
$$
but it couldn't be possible because $U+V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

My intuition is that $\dim(U + V )$ is equal to the number of linearly independent vectors in $B_v \cup B_u$. So my idea is to first calculate $\dim(U + V)$, and then I have that
$$
\dim(U \cap V) = \dim(U) + \dim(V) - \dim(U+V).
$$

So I constructed a matrix having each basis's vectors as rows:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
    0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
   -1 & -1 & 1 & 3 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Luckily it's easy to prove that the rank of this matrix is $4$ (by applying Laplace expansion to the $2$nd row and calculating the determinant of a $4 \times 4$ submatrix). Therefore, there are $4$ linearly independent vectors in $B_v \cup B_u$, so $\dim(U+V) = 4$ and $\dim(U \cap V) = 1$.

My questions are: is this a reasonable way to solve this exercise? Is there a faster way to get a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this idea of combining the bases, putting them as rows (or columns) in a matrix and computing the rank is fine.

I'm concerned about the usage of the Laplace expansion; the Laplace expansion (at least, as I understand it) is only applicable to square matrices, as is the determinant it computes. Perhaps I've misunderstood what you've done, but it sounds like your method is suspect at this point.

That said, if you've simply eliminated the second row and computed the $4 \times 4$ determinant as non-zero, then adding another row cannot reduce the rank, so the matrix would still be of full rank $4$. Note that this is equivalent to showing that the combined bases, without the vector $(0, -1, 0, 0)$ forms a basis for $\Bbb{R}^4$, so adding an extra vector will still produce a spanning set.

A more reliable method would be to row-reduce the $5 \times 4$ matrix (or its transpose) and count the pivots. Also, once you get to $4 \times 4$ matrices or larger, row reduction starts to become faster than determinant calculation using Laplace's expansion.

Here's the way I "eyeballed" this. Like you, I decided to show that $U + V = \Bbb{R}^4$. Taking $B_V$ at face value; a basis for $V$ as claimed, this means that $V$ is $3$-dimensional. We simply need to find a vector in $U$ that is not in $V$, and $U + V$ will be a strictly larger subspace, which can only be all of $\Bbb{R}^4$.

The presence of $(0, -1, 0, 0)$ means we can essentially ignore the second coordinate; it can be adjusted independently. Similarly, we can form $(0, 0, 0, 4)$ as a difference of two vectors in $B_V$, and hence it is in $V$. Thus, we can ignore the fourth coordinate too. In the other basis vectors, I note that the first and third coordinates sum to $0$, so each vector in $B_V$ (and hence in $V$) is orthogonal to $(1, 0, 1, 0)$.

Since at least one of (in fact, both) the vectors in $B_U$ is not orthogonal to $(1, 0, 1, 0)$, neither vector lies in $V$. Thus, $U + V$ is a strictly larger subspace than $V$, and hence must be $\Bbb{R}^4$. The dimension formula tells us that $\dim(U \cap V) = 1$, as you computed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! As regards Laplace's expansion, I apologize for the misunderstanding: what I did was compute the determinant of a 4x4 submatrix (e.g. the one obtained if you remove the 5th row). Applying Laplace's expansion along the 2nd row is particularly convenient due to the presence of three zeroes, so I actually just had to compute a single 3x3 determinant.